# ¿Cómo eliminar valores repetidos de una misma fila en una matriz?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Quería pedirles ayuda con este proyecto a partir de funciones, donde debo llenar una matriz con números aleatorios de 1 y 2 pasa que luego debo digitar la fila y columna donde se encuentra el valor a pasar a 0 y tanto los valores que estén iguales a la izquierda como a la derecha deben de eliminarse pongo un ejemplo.

2 1 2 1 2 1
2 1 2 **2** 2 1

Entonces supongamos que al digitar la fila y columna del 2 en negrita debo borrar tanto el dos a la izquierda como el 2 a la derecha pero sin tocar el primer 2 de la fila 2 de la matriz por así decirlo seria una eliminación solo por bloques, a pesar de ser el primer 2 de la segunda fila un valor repetido no puedo pasarlo a 0 ya que solo puedo borrar por bloques.

Luego debo desplazar ese bloque al inicio de la fila ya pasados a 0 y los demás a la derecha de ese bloque entonces quedaría así:

2 1 2 1 2 1
**0** **0** **0** 2 1 1

Entonces el desplazamiento quedaría así.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//prototipos de las funciones y sus variables para trabajar en ellas
//se necesitan las matrices, y dos variables de tipo int para las filas y columnas
void mostrarMatriz(int[][9],int,int);
int numeroaleatorio();
void llenarMatriz(int[][9],int,int);
void crearMatrizcopia(int[][9],int[][9],int,int);
void imprimirMatrizcopia(int[][9],int,int);
void rangocalculado(int[][9],int);
void eliminarbloque(int[][9],int);

int main(){
    int Matriz[9][9];//matriz original
    int Matrizcopia[9][9];//copia de la matriz original

    llenarMatriz(Matriz,9,9);
    mostrarMatriz(Matriz,9,9);
    crearMatrizcopia(Matrizcopia,Matriz,9,9);
    imprimirMatrizcopia(Matrizcopia,9,9);
    rangocalculado(Matrizcopia,9,9);


 return 0;
}

int numeroaleatorio(){
    int aleatorio;
    aleatorio = 1 + rand() % 2;//
    return aleatorio;
}

void llenarMatriz(int Matriz[9][9],int filas,int columnas){
    int aleatorio;
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
        aleatorio = numeroaleatorio();
        Matriz[i][j] = aleatorio;
        }
    }
}

void mostrarMatriz(int Matriz[9][9],int filas,int columnas){
    cout<<"Matriz Original"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
           cout<<Matriz[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void crearMatrizcopia(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int Matriz[9][9],int filas, int columnas){
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
           Matrizcopia[i][j] = Matriz[i][j];//pasar datos de la matriz original a la copia
        }
    }
}

void imprimirMatrizcopia(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int filas, int columnas){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Matriz Copia"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0 ; i<filas; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columnas; j++){
           cout<<Matrizcopia[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void rangocalculado(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int fc ){
    do{
    cout << "Insertar la fila-columna a eliminar :";
        cin >> fc;
    } while (fc <= 0 );
    eliminarbloque(Matrizcopia,9,9);
}

void eliminarbloque(int Matrizcopia[9][9],int fc){
    Matrizcopia[fc / 10][fc % 10] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, tus matrices son de tamaño fijo, no hace falta que estés pasando a todas las funciones las dimensiones de la matriz.

Es mejor solución declarar dos valores constantes y usarlos directamente allí donde los necesitemos. Esta solución te permite cambiar facilmente el tamaño de la matriz:

```
int constexpr FILAS = 9;
int constexpr COLUMNAS = 9;

// ...

int Matriz[FILAS][COLUMNAS];
```

Por otro lado, revisa las llamadas a las funciones porque tu código ni tan siquiera compila. Las declaraciones tienen unos parámetros y las implementaciones otros diferentes.

Nota, por ejemplo, que la función `rangocalculado` no debe recibir el parámetro `fc` ya que esa debería ser una variable local de la función.

Tratando ya tu problema, vas a trabajar por filas, así que, para evitar demasiada redundancia, podemos coger el puntero a la fila:

```
int* fila = Matrizcopia[fc/10];
```

Y luego, ya, tratando el problema, lo primero que puedes hacer es una copia del valor a eliminar

```
int posicion = fc % 10;
int numero = fila[posicion];
```

Este número lo puedes usar para calcular el rango de columnas a eliminar:

```
int inicio = posicion;
for ( int i=inicio-1; i>=0 && fila[i]==numero; i--, inicio--); 

int fin = posicion;
for ( int i=fin+1; i<9 && fila[i]==numero; i++, fin++);
```

Y finalmente toca poner los valores a 0 y moverlos al origen de la fila

```
if (inicio > 0)
{
    for (int i=inicio-1, j=fin; i>=0; i--, j--)
    {
        fila[j] = fila[i];
        fila[i] = 0;
    }
}
else 
{
    for (int i=inicio; i<=fin; i++ )
        fila[i] = 0;
}
```

> si tengo 2 **1** 2 ejemplo  el problema es que no me puede pasar a  0 ese valor, como minimo debe de ser 2 valores para pasarlos a 0 y transladarlos al inicio de la fila, sorry por no comentar eso

Mi primer consejo al respecto es que te pongas las pilas. Nadie de este portal se va a sentar a tu lado en el examen y, sinceramente, ese cambio es tan trivial que en otras situaciones no te habría ni contestado.

Si quieres que el algoritmo solo funcione cuando haya 2 o más coincidencias basta con comparar `inicio` y `fin`

```
if (fin > inicio)
{
    // ...
}
```

Si te estás preguntando dónde debes poner eso, no voy a ser tan explícito, pero ahí va una pista: si `fin==inicio` entonces no deberías mover ni reemplazar ningún valor

Comment: ok gracias dejame ver si me sale jajaj

Comment: hola @eferion como estas me ayudaste mucho con tu aporte te lo agradesco, pero tu codigo no me funciona cuando ingreso la posicion a pasar a 0 solo me pasa esa posicion y me la traslada al principio pero no hace lo mismo con los valores repetidos que estan tanto a la izquierda como derecha, tienes alguna sujerencia?

Comment: el codigo esta bien, solo que fue mi error no explicarme mas a a detalle pero los bloques son como minimo de 2 si ahorita pongo una posicion donde el valor es individual osea 2 **1** 2, osea solo se pueden pasar a 0 bloques de minimo 2 valores de 1s o 2s entonces eso se me olvido decirlo alli perdon, sera que me des una sujerencia para hacerlo

Comment: si tengo 2 **1** 2 ejemplo  el problema es que no me puede pasar a  0 ese valor, como minimo debe de ser 2 valores para pasarlos a 0 y transladarlos al inicio de la fila, sorry por no comentar eso

Comment: sorry por parecer tan nub @eferion jajaj pero igualmente te agradesco tu respuesta lo pondre en practica y si es que estos son proyectos para practicar aun no entro en mi examen, entonces ando practicando lo mas que pueda, pero tu logica me costaba un poco entenderla pero yendo sobre la marcha la ya estoy comprendiendo mas jajaj pero igualmente te agradesco que te allas tomado la molestia de responderme. Gracias. al menos la logica del amigo de abajo esta bestial ajajajaj, la tuya fue la que mas se apega a lo medio se actualmente pero si igual gracias por el comentario

Comment: @IsaacNewton no te preocupes, nadie nace sabiendo. Sigue insistiendo que es el buen camino

Comment: @IsaacNewton como has borrado la pregunta no puedo contestarte por ahí. No me molesta ni tengo problemas en responder a dudas. Lo que intento que veas es que es probable que antes de afrontar este problema debas reforzar tu base de programación. Piensa que en un hipotético examen o entrevista de trabajo nosotros no vamos a estar ahí, luego la idea es que entiendas las respuestas y ello te ayude a formarte y a mejorar. Si no entiendes las respuestas entonces estamos perdiendo el tiempo

Comment: @IsaacNewton por otro lado, lo siento si te has sentido atacado con mis comentarios. No es algo que pretenda ni mucho menos. Piensa que en estos chats no existe el lenguaje no verbal y es facil confundir las intenciones de quien escribe

Comment: gracias igual por tus consejos y comentarios

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, tienes que aclarar tu concepto de "*eliminar de una matriz*"; no es posible eliminar datos de una matriz ya que su tamaño de datos es invariante. Tú te refieres a que almacenar un cero (`0`) en la matriz es equivalente a no tener datos; pero eso no es *eliminar*, eso es una convención.

Todo tu algoritmo se puede resumir en dos pasos a aplicar en secuencias de datos (en tu caso filas de matriz):

1. Si se encuentran tres valores seguidos, cambiar dos de los valores por cero.
2. Reordenar la secuencia dejando los ceros en el extremo izquierdo y conservando el orden del resto de elementos.

Para el primer paso, puedes usar la función [`std::search_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n) de la cabecera [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm):

```
int valores[] = {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1};

std::cout << "Antes: ";
for (const auto &valor : valores)
    std::cout << valor << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

auto bloque = std::search_n(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores), 3, 2);
//                          \                    \                   \  \______ Valor del bloque
//                           \                    \                   \________ Tamanyo del bloque
//                            \                    \____ Fin de la busqueda
//                             \________________________ Inicio de la busqueda

if (bloque != std::end(valores))
{
    bloque[0] = 0;
    bloque[1] = 0;
    bloque[2] = 0;
}

std::cout << "Despues: ";
for (const auto &valor : valores)
    std::cout << valor << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##tZLdS8MwFMWfm7/iOsF2MNmHb20nCCL4Lr5sMrI02wLZzcyHIGN/e03Tlc2O6Xzw0ofm9PZ3DuSwzeaWSYrLsrwWyKQrOORCGas5Xd@Tg0blUmlhV14kAi2sqcCkS7Ykqk4fVCrNzeQNxrAd9WDYg1HzDHcZIZGxRZoy5SzkOXQe0HKTQicj0UJpSJhCY4E6q@AmsCBtmF0Sff@5/u5fYoizFjieYly5BdJcqnfHfaKwYjjVbDXDJJzmfOnzNxa9eoVjcSTd@fRdb9Dvw9mZXip6bToLA68hf8HlPuDPDn@wmO0HXuia4qe63OOMSYA9CfQgkBTmznhUQX@DHZK0B55RMKHaPN@hBST767oan16G74AvWlRvTAZVywbZQRi2hVEj7E6a98jNxv1r9zS3TmNlvyvLLw):

> ```
> Antes: 2 1 2 2 2 1 
> Despues: 2 1 0 0 0 1
> ```

En cuanto al segundo paso, puedes usar la función [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) de la misma cabecera, pero pasando una lambda que use como criterio para ordenar el hecho de que el valor sea cero:

```
int valores[] = {2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};

std::cout << "Antes: ";
for (const auto &valor : valores)
    std::cout << valor << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

std::sort(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores), [](int a, int b) { return a == 0; });
//        \                    \                  \                         \_____ Si el primer termino es cero
//         \                    \                  \________ Criterio de orden
//          \                    \____ Fin de la ordenacion
//           \________________________ Inicio de la ordenacion

std::cout << "Despues: ";
for (const auto &valor : valores)
    std::cout << valor << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##tVLRaoMwFH02X3HoYCo42u5R62BsDPa8x7aUNN51AU0kiXuRfrtTW9dWOujLDoHcnMs5J@FGlOWDyLnaNc2dVCKvMsJCausM8eKJnTie77SR7qslmVQOBZcqCFnNvO70zXNtyC7XSFE/RphHmA1rvk8Y86zL4ljoymGxwORZObIxJgnzPrVBILSyDrxyGve9F@LBM2TepfjQbwsffjIy9lfK/02z2rigr7a0a287GEboSVLZGbVcB91DeIRu24aoYchVRoEjTTFLsA/btOkUR6xwBaubqKGz6YAPCcpRGlmQgSNTSKVBFoKMPg@8PXFzBF7aiZGRGu0EtclIXfj9Ydgr36TqRDk/6LiQeiQ@xYyBdyXFIfRSP/4Fr2TL6l//wXGEs4Ttm@YH):

> ```
> Antes: 2 1 0 0 0 1 
> Despues: 0 0 0 2 1 1
> ```

Con esto tenemos los ingredientes para lo que necesitas:

```
constexpr int tamanyo = 9;
// Alias de datos para hacer el código más comprensible
using Matriz = int[tamanyo][tamanyo];
using Fila = int[tamanyo];

void mostrar(const Matriz &m)
{
    for (auto &fila : m)
    {
        for (auto &valor : fila)
            std::cout << valor << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

/* Procesamos una fila:
 Se cambian por 0 todos los 2 seguidos y se reordena dejando los 0 a la izquierda. */
void procesa(Fila &f)
{
    for (int ancho = tamanyo; ancho != 1; --ancho)
    {
        do
        {
            auto bloque = std::search_n(std::begin(f), std::end(f), ancho, 2);
            if (bloque != std::end(f))
            {
                for (auto inicio = bloque, fin = bloque + ancho; inicio != fin; ++inicio)
                    *inicio = 0;
            }
            else
                break;
        } while (true);
        std::sort(std::begin(f), std::end(f), [](int a, int b) { return a == 0; });
    }
}

// Procesamos una matriz.
void procesa(Matriz &m)
{
    for (auto &fila : m)
        procesa(fila);
}
```

En cada fila se buscan los bloques de números `2` y se substituyen por ceros, empezamos buscando de bloques grandes a pequeños porque (obviamente) los bloques pequeños están contenidos en los grandes.

He obtenido [el siguiente resultado](https://tio.run/##jVJNT@MwED3Hv2IQok22rQR726bdIzd@AYuQ6zithWMXx4HdrfLby8zkoxVCwCXyvJl5b@Zl1H6/UFa67fF4aZyyTaFhZXwdg5bVb3HCpN36YOIOQaG8q6P@uw9gXIQoK@n@eVjDr1w0tXFbuJMxmP@IYP6@zz@Mj6Hq1lj5riYX4sWbAoK2VjsZ0p5pUmXiIJLSB0hlEz1MSmpeAuLJOfwiLQZLoDSlkg5YQ1rHYrkM0hVpBlfwM4MZ3OSi7QUrWhn1eDX4jurhC2HWU76JsFpBl8XHFKa5eJec/nEEtuMw@@CVrmXKBk3K0xBkt3RqR2b3luU9cLHGdWCx4Kgfr/D4oUfCM26sf240trJ6rWVQu0fXGbPRW@PSMpt3SY02UcBsc3SLhk5MCWlPcrE@L@SFWejMEuOMMjRp1zJHa9wYofvMnQ9lSIj5HGazDmDKJPkxslzzCC19tK01pzd4pU@Et/C6M1ZDGkOjs9Hh2of46X73D52nc77kTQYHPL3YBAd4maQJbfbhr/nWXQ7FfBN8a6RSSZyE23qSChXGg69Ib7hGDgYWDj46nLPqRBAVL4B@tcfjGw):

> ```
> 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 
> 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 
> 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 
> 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 
> 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 
> 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 
> 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 
> 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 
> 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 
>
> 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 
> 0 0 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 
> 0 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
> 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 1 
> 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 
> 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 
> 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 1 2 
> 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2
> ```

Comment: soy un poco novato, y si te comento que esta bastante duro entenderle a tu codigo jajaja amigo, no tienes una forma mas facil de hacerlo?

Comment: es que veo que tu codigo esta bastante avanzado y yo me imaginaba algun tipo de funcion con if para pasar los valores a 0 y alguna otra funcion con un for para correr los valores a la izquierda, algo asi no se puede hacer?

Comment: @IsaacNewton la manera más fácil de hacerlo es la que ofrezco, usar `if` y `for` para hacer tareas para las que ya existe una serie de funciones es reinventar la rueda. Si algo te resulta confuso, te animo a crear nuevas preguntas para resolver las dudas que te surjan ¡es la manera de aprender!.